# Помощь со списками питон

Tags: python

`[31, 311, 301, 291, 281, 28]` - мой список, что прописать что бы на выходе получалось `[(31, 311),(311, 301),(301, 291),(291, 281),(281, 28)]`

Comment: Для начала, прописать ваш код, который вы не указали, позже, возможно, найдется решение

Answer (score 0):

Решение тривиально. Добавить проверку входных параметров оставлю вам.

```py
def transform_list(a):
    return [(a[i], a[i + 1]) for i in range(len(a) - 1)]
```

Comment: не нужно решать учебные задания за других. подобные вопросы не приветствуются на сайте и, обычно, закрываются.

Comment: учебные задания? о чем вы?